# how to define a variable char in symbols?

Tags: c, variables, compiler-errors

i am working in c (i am really a beginner at coding), i want to write a functions tha allows me to translate the text i write in the prompt in morse. So i am trying by define my variables from the letter of the elphabet to the respective morse code but i always get a warning of multi-character and don't know how to move on.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <malloc.h>
//funzione per scrivere codice morse
int main()
{
    char a='.-';
    printf("%c",a);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `char` is just a single character. For multiple characters you have to use a string, `char a[] = ".-";`

Comment: Useful ref [Letters, numbers, punctuation, prosigns for Morse code and non-Latin variants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morse_code#Letters,_numbers,_punctuation,_prosigns_for_Morse_code_and_non-Latin_variants).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What @Barmar told you is correct:

```
char a[] = ".-";`
```

You also tell us that you were trying to defining the mapping from letters to morse code.  This could be using a `struct` along with a `lookup` function to lookup each letter:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct map {
    char letter;
    char *morse;
};

// return morse string for letter, or NULL if not found
const char *lookup(const struct map *m, const char letter) {
    for(unsigned i = 0; m[i].letter; i++) {
        if(m[i].letter == letter)
            return m[i].morse;
    }
    return NULL;
}

int main() {
    struct map m[] = {
        { 'A', (char *) ".-" },
        { 'B', (char *) "-..." },
        // ...
        { '\0', NULL }
    };
    printf("%c => %s\n", 'A', lookup(m, 'A'));
}
```

Once you get a little more experience you can replace the `lookup()` function with `lfind()` or if the map is sorted by letter `bsearch()`.